# cropping and ajax uploading of image

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, image, upload

I want to upload and crop an image via ajax.

Please suggest how I can do this.

Comment: You could try and look at jQuery's plugin pages, i'm sure you'll find a plugin that does that.

Comment: Which server side language you are using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To upload an image you will need javascript process handling the upload , there are plenty plugins to do it if you are using jquery library. 
To handle uploading process you will need php script. You are sending request to php script from ajax and it does the upload .

To crop image you need a crop tool or crop script here is a cool one http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-image-crop-plugin-jcrop/

After you handled cropped image you need to execute uploading process (php) by jquery uploader plugin , or another jquery or javascript ajax code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code Jquery + PHP  [Cake PHP]

View file upload.ctp

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://demos.9lessons.info/ajaximageupload/scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#photoimg').on('change', function(){
    $("#preview").html('');
    $("#preview").html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview',success: showResponse}).submit();
  });

});


</script>

<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='/media/upload'>
Upload image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>

<div id='preview'></div>



create a function with name upload in Media controller



  function upload(){
       $this->layout = '';

      $session_id='1'; // User session id
      $path = "images/media/images/original/";
      $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp","jpeg");

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
      //pr($_FILES);die;
      //if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        $name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
        $size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
          if(strlen($name)) {
          list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
            if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)){
                if($size<(1024*1024)) { // Image size max 1 MB
                $txt=str_replace(" ","_",$txt);
                $actual_image_name = $txt."_".time().".".$ext;
                $tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
                App::import('Vendor', 'resize');
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$actual_image_name)) {  //Code for image resize
                  //mysql_query("UPDATE users SET profile_image='$actual_image_name' WHERE uid='$session_id'");
                  // save this to DB into Temp Selection table set USer wise and Capsule or individual Board wise
                  echo "<img src='/images/media/images/".$actual_image_name."' class='preview'><br/><a href='javascript:void(0);' id='upload_submit'>Submit</a>";
                }
                else
                echo "failed";
                }
            else
            echo "Image file size max 1 MB";
            }
          else
          echo "Invalid file fo`enter code here`rmat..";
          }
        else
        echo "Please select image..!";
        exit;
      }

    }
```